# Solr metrics API get number of docs

Tags: solr, metrics

I'm not sure what is the correct property to get the number of docs with the new metrics API in Solr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to the URL directly will give you all available metrics. If you search this list for `doc`, one of the first hits will be:

```
  "SEARCHER.searcher.maxDoc":3,
  "SEARCHER.searcher.numDocs":3,
```

These are located under the `metrics/solr.core.<core_name>` element.

Comment: Why is it in SEARCHER node ? So what does SEARCHER mean ?

Comment: The IndexSearcher is the internal module responsible for searching your index. It's the module that actually knows how many documents are available in the currently searchable index (and when a commit happens, a new searcher is created, and then swapped in when it's ready - if that takes some time, the number of documents doesn't change before they become visible when a new searcher is opened and ready).